# Lateral control for autonomous vehicles ( steering angle problem)

Tags: control, simulation, matlab, motion-planning, autonomous-car

I am working on a control system for autonomous vehicles, i am using a kinematic bicycle model simulated on matlab simulink and the formula i used for the steering angle is given in the figures below along with the code and my simulink model:
[image: formula]

```
x=roadCenters(:,1);
y=roadCenters(:,2);

% Your data
t = 1:size(x)
 % Fit a third-degree polynomial to the x-coordinates
px = polyfit(t, x, 3);

   % Fit a third-degree polynomial to the y-coordinates
py = polyfit(t, y, 3);

   % Find the first derivative of x(t) and y(t)

   dx = polyder(px);
   dy = polyder(py);

   % Find the second derivative of x(t) and y(t)
   d2x = polyder(dx);
   d2y = polyder(dy);

  % Calculate the curvature
  k = abs(polyval(dx, t).*polyval(d2y, t) - polyval(dy, t).*polyval(d2x, t)) ./ (polyval(dx, 
  t).^2 + polyval(dy, t).^2).^(3/2);

  % the steering angle
  d=atan(L*k);

  % moving d to simulink

  t = (0:length(d)-1)'; % Create a time vector
  D= timeseries(d, t); % Create a timeseries object
```

[image]
Result :
[image: result]

Questions:

what is wrong with my path tracking ? i suspect :

-The data transfer from script to simulink isn't right and is giving insufficient data;

-The speed profile that i chose is not compatible with the path tracking .

[image: speed]